# No permissions to open this file

Tags: windows-10

I have completed formatted my laptop,using a new win 10 os and permissions on my external hard drive have been deleted from the previous windows and and cannot access files!

Anytime I try opening files from that folder, Im told you don't have permission to view this file. Check the permissions and try again.

And also the files are encrypted and when I try decrypting it, it says that you will need to provide administrator permission to change these attributes.An error occurred applying attributes to file. Access denied.

Comment: You’ll need to give us about ten times as much information as that before we can begin to help you.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: External HDDs default ownership is set to Everyone.  If you have ownership issues you will have to provide us the ACL in question, without that information, we cannot explain the behavior.  However, if the files are encrypted, that changes everything.  If you did not back up the certificate used to encrypt the files, then the files cannot be decrypted, even if you change their ownership

Comment: So what do I do now I don't have the certificate, cos I formatted the laptop completely before installing a new Os

Answer (score -1):

Run a command prompt with administrator privilege and try to the takeown command:

```
takeown /f directory /r
```

The /r for recursive.

Comment: Don't understand

Comment: That changes the files to be owned by your user so you can change permission on them.

Comment: It's not working, do I replace the directory with something else